# Identify AWS service for fast retrival of data

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have one generic question, actually, I am hunting for a solution to a problem,

Currently, we are generating the reports directly from the oracle database, now from the performance perspective, we want to migrate data from oracle to any specific AWS service which could perform better. We will pass data from that AWS service to our reporting software.

Could you please help which service would be idle for this?

Thanks,
Vishwajeet

Answer (score 0):

To answer well, additional info is needed:

- How much data is needed to generate a report?
- Are there any transformed/computed values needed?
- What is good performance? 1 second? 30 seconds?
- What is the current query time on Oracle and what kind of query? Joins, aggregations etc.